# how to call c function in c++ using arm-crasscompiler

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, archlinux, linux-mint

the below make file which I have posted is for cpp and i want to compile 2 c files in the same Makefile and link that with the cpp object files so. how can I do that please guide to construct 
 In the below make file for Ex: I want to add 2 c files file1.c file1.h, file2.c and file2.h

how can I add this in the below Makefile.

### Makefile

```
EXENAME = demo

CPPS += \
main.cpp\
features.cpp

CPP_DEPS += \
main.d\
features.d

OBJS += \
main.o\
features.o

INCLUDEPATH = -I.
COMPILEOPTS = -O3 -c -fPIC -MP -w -MMD -c $(INCLUDEPATH)
RPATHOPTS = -Wl,-rpath="."
LIBOPTS = -L. -lEIddk2000\
    -lpthread
LINKOPTS = -Wl -o "$(EXENAME)"

############################################################
## TOOLCHAIN PATH CONFIGURATION ############################
## User should modify here  ############################

TOOLCHAIN_GCC = /home/root/Desktop/angstrom-2011.03-i686-linux-armv7a-linux-gnueabi-toolchain/usr/local/angstrom/arm/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-gcc

TOOLCHAIN_LIBS += -L/home/root/Desktop/arm-compiler/angstrom-2011.03-i686-linux-armv7a-linux-gnueabi-toolchain/usr/local/angstrom/arm/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/lib

## TOOLCHAIN PATH CONFIGURATION END ########################
############################################################
all: $(EXENAME)
$(EXENAME): $(OBJS) 
    @echo "Linking..."
    $(TOOLCHAIN_GCC) $(TOOLCHAIN_LIBS) $(LINKOPTS) $(OBJS) $(LIBOPTS) $(RPATHOPTS)
    @echo "Done."
    @echo ""

%.o : %.cpp
    $(TOOLCHAIN_GCC) $(COMPILEOPTS) $<
clean :
```

### rm -rf $(OBJS) $(CPP_DEPS) $(EXENAME)

Answer (score 0):

For only compiling part you can use following changes in the Makefile

```
  file%.o:file%.c file%.h
           $(TOOLCHAIN_GCC) $(COMPILEOPTS) $<
```

After this you need to make changes in linking of the object files to generate the final executable file.

Comment: please suggest me how to change in linking of the object files to generate executable.

Comment: I have few c and c++ files I want to compile those to generate a single executable. using a Makefile please suggest me how to do it by using the above make.

Comment: It depends on what is your requirement and how many files you need for successful compilation, etc to generate the final executable. It needs information of all the dependencies required for it and then only it can be used to get the final executable